# Distributing code between multiple <script> tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume I have the following code inside my HTML file, within the `<body>` tags:

```
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    class Element extends React.Component {...}

    ReactDOM.render(<Element />, document.getElementById("root");
</script>
```

The above code works flawlessly. However, if I change it to the following:

```
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    class Element extends React.Component {...}

</script>

<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<Element />, document.getElementById("root");
</script>
```

I just see a blank screen.

Why does React not work if the `ReactDOM.render()` call is made from a separate tag?

Comment: Do you get errors in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your scripts are of type `text/babel`, which means they'll get transformed into JavaScript and evaluated in different scopes. You can possibly store the class in a global variable, and retrieve it to use it in a different scope, like so:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  class Element extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      );
    }
  }
  
  window['Element'] = Element;
</script>

<script type="text/babel">
  var Element = window['Element']; 
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Element />, 
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

It works fine

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

 <script type="text/babel">
   class Element extends React.Component {
    render(){
     return (
      <div>Hello</div>
     )
    }
   }
 </script>
 
 <script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render( <Element/>, document.getElementById('root') );
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the another demo on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/92qv025204

Comment: Wow, it works when importing via the given URLs, but not from locally stored .js files. I will look into the differences. Maybe different versions?